# Nodejs: Chroma key/composite two images

Tags: node.js, image, composite

I'm looking to composite one image on top of another, but the location and size will be determined by a green box in the original image.

Is this something I can do w/ [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)?

Thanks!

--

Here's what I'm hoping to do:

[image: example]

--

**Edit:** It looks like [OpenCV](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs) is a great place to start. After some digging, I'm thinking these are the correct steps:

1. Detect if there is a square with a specific color in the image
2. Capture the coordinates & dimensions of that square
3. Create the new image by compositing `face.jpg` on top of the original image

I'm not quite sure the best path to approach step 1.